# How to stop background auto generated notification by fcm?

Tags: android, push-notification

When application in foreground **onMessageReceived** return the data but when application in background **onMessageReceived** don't return anything.
FCM will generate auto notification while application in background or kill mode
I want to stop auto generated notification.

This is my sample code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage);
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    handleNow(remoteMessage);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used Notification tray for it and it will call your onMessageReceived() method at that time.

Please check below link this helps to you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Please add data tag into your json response like below:

```
  {
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this does not work. When FCM see "notification" key, does not matter the "data" key.

Answer (score 4):

With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:

1.**Notification messages** - Sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.

2.**Data messages**-which are handled by the client app.

> Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by onMessageReceived():

So if you are using notification messages which are high priority messages you will not get callback in onMessageReceived() if your app is in background . Use **Data message** instead .

Follow the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Your Data message should look like this.

```
{
 "message":{
"token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"data":{
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "body" : "great match!",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
  }
 }
 }
```